# Deleting images in array

Tags: functions, forms, attachments

Is it possible to delete all the images with ID's given in input field?

I have field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="deleteimg" value="3008,3009,3010,3011,3012" class="something">
```

I'm getting field on POST:

```
$todelete = SOMEimp::request( 'deleteimg' ) );
```

Then I wanted to get all the values with:

```
$imgarray = explode(',', $var);
```

I was trying with:

```
wp_delete_attachment( $imgarray, true)
```

But it doesn't accept arrays I guess or for some other reason it doesn't work.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you try with loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[wp_delete_attachment](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_attachment)** not support array, this function support integer value only, so you have to perform this function inside loop.

```
<?php 
$imgarray = explode(',', $var);
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($imgarray); $i++) {
   wp_delete_attachment( $imgarray[$i], true);
}
?>
```